# Uploading mp3 to NodeJS Express server corrupts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, file-upload

I would like to upload an MP3 file from my web client to a Node Express server. I can upload the file, then write it to disk. However, the file gets corrupted and I cannot play the song using an MP3 player.

If it makes a difference, the file is being uploaded from an OS X machine, then gets written to an Ubuntu server. The size of the uploaded of the uploaded file is larger than the original. I receive no errors in this workflow. Nothing goes wrong until I start to play the file.

Please see below for my code. Any ideas about why I'm experiencing this?

CLIENT

```
uploadSong: (song) => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/song', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    },
    body: song
  })
  .then( response => {
    console.log("Got response after uploading song:", response);
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.log("Error in Firebase AC upload song: ", error);
  });
}
```

SERVER

```
app.put("/song", (req, res) => {
  var mp3SongName = 'test.mp3';
  var mp3_file = fs.createWriteStream(mp3SongName);

  mp3_file.on('open', function (fd) {
    req.on('data', function(data){
        console.log("loading... \n");
        mp3_file.write(data);
    }); 

    req.on('end', function(){
        console.log("finalizing...");
        mp3_file.end();
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: To help diagnose I suggest creating a text file with a similar size and uploading that. Then you can look at the contents of the file on disk to get a sense of how it differs from the file you sent.

Comment: I'm suspicious of this line: `body: song`. My guess would be that `song` is not what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @skirtle  

Good call. I tried uploading a test file with nothing but "TEST" written in it. The resulting file read:  "data:text/plain;base63,<some base64 encoded string>"  

I then inspected the mp3 file. It read:<br/>
        data:text/plain;base63,<some base64 encoded string>

Answer (score 2):

I noticed when inspecting the uploaded files that the data was getting written as a base64 encoded string.

I traced this back to my client code, which was using the [FileReader.readAsDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) method to read the file:

> ...the result attribute contains  the data as a URL representing the file's data as a **base64 encoded** string

Mystery solved. Now I just need to figure out whether to decode the file on the server, or use a FileReader method that doesn't encode this in the first place.

Comment: The solution was to just file straight to the server without reading it. That preserved the default encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for file uploading. This is the server side code. I named it as `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var rand;
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        //callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
                //callback(null, file.originalname)
        rand=Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);

        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + rand);

    }

})
var upload = multer({
        storage: storage});
app.get('/api/file',function(req,res){
res.sendfile('E:/syed ayesha/nodejs/uploads/video/views/video.html');
});
app.post('/api/file',upload.single('userFile'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.file.path);
    res.send(rand);

})
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("working on port 3000");
});
```

create a views folder and place this html file in it. I named as `video.html`

```
<form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/api/file"
      method="post"
>
 <input type="file" name="userFile"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">

</form>
```

Run the server a `node server.js`. Open the browser and run this api `http://localhost:3000/api/file` and choose any file it may `audio/video/pdf/image etc`..any file you want to upload to disk. In this code I am uploading my files to `public/uploads` in this root project folder. You can give your destination folder from where you want to store the uploaded files. Hope this helps.